# Incompatible receiver, Map required! (Issue with Android)

Tags: android, dictionary, react-native, package, react-native-calendars

I am using this component https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars. It Works good in iphone but having issue with android. When i open calendar page it gives me an error as

**Incompatible receiver, Map required!**

Environment
List of Packages Installed

"react-native": "^0.52.0",

"react-native-calendars": "^1.20.0"

Seems like there is an issue with core-js.I have also tried everything from this reference link https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/368

[image]

Do anybody know, How to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Reverting back to v2.5.2 of core-js fixed it. We use core-js via babel-preset-env, in order to get it fixed the solution is to set the version hard in the resolutions property of the package.json file:

```
"resolutions": {

    "core-js": "2.5.2"
 }
```

the resolutions section of the package.json file is a yarn feature!